# Writing to file a UNICODE character from HEX input

Tags: c#, unicode, type-conversion

I have a HEX input (eg. 394A) and I need to encode it as UNICODE, then save the resulting character(s) to a file. How do I go about that?

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
fsDest.Write(StrToUni(uni.ToString()), 0, 2);
private static byte[] StrToUni(string str)
{
     Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
     byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(str);
     return unicodeBytes;
}
```

I should see this in my file: 9J

Comment: What specific Unicode encoding? UTF-8? UTF-16? UTF-32?

Comment: In your sample code, what is the value of `uni`?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to convert a hexademical representation of characters to their **ASCII** equivalent?  If `0x394A` becomes `9J` then it is definitely **not Unciode**. 㥊 is the Unicode character `394A`.

Comment: U+349A ---> 㒚   In other words, if my input were 349A, I should get that character and write it to file. My encoding is UTF-32BE

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16LE. UTF-32BE is `Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-32BE")`. Though is is unusual to use an UTF-32 encoding for files as this encompasses a huge space overhead in contrast to UTF-16 without providing an actual benefit. UTF-32 mostly makes sense in memory when you have algorithms which operate faster on fixed-width characters.